# How can I execute a Mongo `forEach` (or run my own JS) with Monger?

Tags: mongodb, clojure, monger

I'm using Monger to connect to Mongo. I want to run

```
db.collection.find().forEach(function(x) { db.collection-two.insert(...) })
```

I can't see a relevant 'for each' entry in the Monger docs or a way to pass in JavaScript to insert into another collection. How do I do this?

**EDIT** this question was based on a misunderstanding (`forEach` lies in the client API not on the server API). I would delete it but I can't.

Comment: I asked this based on faulty information, the question is invalid. (Can't find an appropriate flagging category, sorry)

Answer (score 5):

You can process each document as a lazy sequence of Clojure maps:

```
(require 'monger.collection)

(doseq [x (monger.collection/find-maps "your-collection")]
  ;you can process x here, which is a vanilla clojure map
  (println x))
```

Why are you trying to use JavaScript?  Are you using ClojureScript, or are you just thinking in terms of how you would write code from the mongodb shell?

**Disclaimer:**  Using `doseq` here is not functional, and probably not idiomatic depending on what you are trying to accomplish.  Using `map` or `reduce` is probably better, I was just trying to write something that most closely aligned with your `forEach` example code.

**Related:**

- [Monger Guide - Finding Documents](http://clojuremongodb.info/articles/querying.html#finding_documents)

Comment: Thanks. Not quite what I want though. I want to run this in the mongod process. The reason for this is largely bottlenecks. I'm going to do this on approx 10 million records, so it matters. On closer inspection it looks like this is a shell command not a server one, which renders my question invalid.

Comment: @Joe are you sure its faster to run this in the mongod process?  I have no clue, but I am curious if you've actually run any performance tests?  Of course that assumes your Clojure process is running locally and not on a remote server.

Comment: Well it's not possible to do it, so a moot point. But yes, I'm dealing with a lot of small bits of data. I've seen the time difference between single updates and big batches. I'm confident that it's worth figuring out making what I want to do happen on the server. Thanks for your answer, but the question was mistaken and I'll delete it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [command](http://reference.clojuremongodb.info/monger.core.html#var-command) function from monger and [eval](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/#dbcmd.eval) mongodb command

```
(ns user
  (:require [monger.core :as mg]
            [monger.core :as mc]))

;; (command {:eval "function() { db.collection.find().forEach() }"}

(mg/connect!)
(mg/set-db! (mg/get-db "test"))
(mc/command {:eval "function() { db.fs.files.find().forEach(function(x) { })}"})
```